# Cannot open project in visual studio 2012 from another pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've created new website in visual studio 2012. I've already made around 500 lines of code, but now I would like to move this project to my other windows pc which also runs Visual studio 2012.

I've tried to COPY the whole folder and paste it in other pc. I've tried to open it but I get following error:

[image]

What could be the problem here , and how to resolve it?

Comment: How have you configured IIS Express on this new machine?

Comment: Is IIS installed on the other PC?

Comment: What do you mean? I actually only installed VS on both computers. New projects and websites works fine on both computers if they are created on them. Also I can run projects or websites on my local computer too. I did not know that I need to configure something. On both computers everything is the same. ( I installed on both PC's from my original cd )

Comment: What web server is the project using? The dev one, IIS express or full IIS (see the `web` property page of the project)? Does the other computer have it installed?

Comment: Negative votes, please explain..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

right-click the project Solution Explorer and choose Edit ProjectName.csproj"

In the project file, change the following line:
`<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>`
to
`<UseIIS>False</UseIIS>`

Comment: Your answer helped me, but since VS didn't even load the project files into solution explorer I needed to modify file with notepad..

However, it works now.